# Including \bibliography command from separate tex file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, chapters, input, files

I am writing a thesis and I am organizing the contents in the way described on [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents).

In my project folder, the main document is **thesis.tex**. It looks like this:

```
% Write the thesis in report format (thesis.tex)
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

% Insert packages
\usepackage{style}

% Insert preamble
\input{./tex/preamble}

% Begin the thesis
\begin{document}

% Insert title
\input{./tex/title}

% Insert table of contents, figures, and tables
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

% Insert the introduction
\input{./tex/introduction}

% Insert the conclusion
\input{./tex/conclusion}

% Insert the bibliography
\input{./tex/bibliography}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, all the chapters are located in the **tex** subdirectory. In particular, the **tex** subdirectory contains a bib file **tex/references.bib** and a file **tex/bibliography.tex** that looks like this:

```
% Bibliography (tex/bibliography.tex)

% Make the bibliography
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{./references}
```

Now when I compile **thesis.tex**, the bibliography doesn't appear and I get

```
Warning: Citation 'aslam2013' undefined on page 4 on input line 4
```

However, if I instead put the following directly in **thesis.tex**:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{./tex/references}
```

then I get no warning and the bibliography appears.

It's not such a big deal, but I would have liked my bibliography to be organized in a tex file just like the others. Why can't I include the bibliography the way I do? It must be quite obvious for some of you but I really can't see what's wrong...

I'm using Texnic Center on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your paths always have to be relative to the main document - i.e. `thesis.tex`. This applies to `\bibliography`, as well as to `\inputs` and `\includegraphics`. Thus, you have to call

```
\bibliography{./tex/references}
```

inside your file `./tex/bibliography.tex` - even though both files are located in the same directory.

The same applies e.g. to images: in your file `./tex/introduction.tex`, you'll have to include an example image located at `./tex/images/intro_image.jpg` with

```
\includegraphics{./tex/images/intro_image.jpg}
```

and not with `./images/intro_image.jpg`.

Comment: UGH. It was so simple lol.

It works now, thanks very much for the help. It's a good general principle to be aware of.