# Writing Bibliography and main file separately. Then include bib in tex

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing my thesis in chapter format and I have written each chapter separately. Something like shown in code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to write bibliography in same format I do not want to write bibliography entries in my main file.Rather I want to write them in separate bib file then include in my main file. I am not able to do so. I am using TexStudio and bibliography file is also showing extension .tex

Please tell how to write bibliography file and how to include that file in main file.

Comment: you mean something like `\bibliography{test.bib}`? See possibly [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332840/including-bibliography-command-from-separate-tex-file?rq=1)

Comment: Do you really want to write your bibliography yourself? You might have a look at packages like [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)

Comment: yes @Moriambar I want something like this

Comment: @Skillmon I want to copy bibTex from google scholar then include. If their is any better way please tell, I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is. The `biblatex`-package I [linked](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) in my comment is one. You might just google for a `biblatex`-tutorial. It boils down to the following:

- `\usepackage[<options>]{biblatex}` to use the package in your project.
- Put the information you copy from google scholar and the like into a file `<file>.bib`.
- Use `\addbibresource{<file>.bib}` in your project.
- Use the command `\cite{<citation-key>}` (or others provided by `biblatex`) to mark something you cited from your `<file>.bib`.
- Use `\printbibliography` in your project where the bibliography should be printed

When you compile your project compile it with:

1. Run `<latex> <project>` (with `<latex>` the LaTeX-Engine you use)
2. Run `biber <project>`
3. Run LaTeX again to get the bibliography
4. Run LaTeX again to get everything right

This way you get a bibliography which contains all sources you cited (using `\cite` or similar commands).

You can customize the bibliography in multiple ways. This is done with the `options` you pass to `biblatex`-package. You might also take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13513/117050) and perhaps search for a complete tutorial on the web.